# Iostat and top show static resource usage on first value

Tags: macos, unix, cpu, centos, top

For one of my projects, I need to obtain resource (CPU, I/O and disk-space) usage programatically.

Currently I'm running shell commands (`iostat`) and parsing the results which works relatively well for the disk-space stat.

For the CPU and I/O stat on the other-hand, I have a problem.

By testing the `iostat` and `top` command on `Mac OSX 10.9` and `Centos 6.5` the issue is that the very first result that is printed is static.

By "static" I mean constant. It is always the same number no matter how many time you re-run the command. It seems though that the value does change between re-boots.

This is only the case for the very first value, the follow-up values are just fine and reflect the possible system resource usage.

Now the CentOS box I ran the tests on is a VM but the OSX one is just a normal MacBook Pro.

So my three questions are the following:

- How come that the statistics are static - constants on `iostat` and `top` for CPU and I/O usage ?
- How can I fix this ?
- If this can't be fixed or is an intended behaviour, are there alternatives that work both on MacOSX and CentOS ?

Here are sample logs of:

1. A simple one-time `iostat` on CentOS without a refresh:

   `Linux 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64     08/04/2014  _x86_64_    (2 CPU)`

   `avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
             24.64    0.00    0.57    0.10    0.00   74.70`

   `Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
   sda               1.44         0.22        26.26     656556   76917802
   sdb               3.89         0.17        61.83     492714  181116136
   dm-0              3.29         0.22        26.26     647474   76917776
   dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00       2416          0
   dm-2              6.76         0.17        61.83     491914  181116136`
2. A simple `iostat 1` on CentOS but this time with a `1 second` refresh frequency:

`Linux 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64    08/04/2014  _x86_64_    (2 CPU)`

`avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          24.64    0.00    0.57    0.10    0.00   74.70`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               1.44         0.22        26.26     656556   76918018
sdb               3.89         0.17        61.83     492714  181118872
dm-0              3.29         0.22        26.26     647474   76917992
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00       2416          0
dm-2              6.76         0.17        61.83     491914  181118872`

`avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.51    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.49`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               7.00         0.00        56.00          0         56
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-0              7.00         0.00        56.00          0         56
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0`

`avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.00    0.00    1.50    0.50    0.00   97.00`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               3.00         0.00        32.00          0         32
sdb               8.00         0.00       176.00          0        176
dm-0              4.00         0.00        32.00          0         32
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2             14.00         0.00       176.00          0        176`

`avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.51    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.49`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0`

`avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00   98.01`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0`

`avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.50    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00   99.00`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0`

`avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.50    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00   99.00`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0`

`avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.51    0.00    0.00   99.49`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0`

`avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.50    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00   99.00`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sdb               2.00         0.00        24.00          0         24
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              3.00         0.00        24.00          0         24`

`avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.51    0.00    0.51    0.00    0.00   98.99`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sdb               4.00         0.00        80.00          0         80
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              7.00         0.00        80.00          0         80`

Both "experiment" were performed within an interval of a few seconds.

As you can see, for the CPU usage, `%user` is always at `24.64%` and `%system` at `0.57` for the very first value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to get the cpu% programmatically, you may be better getting the information directly from /proc/stat

This is discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017162/how-to-get-total-cpu-usage-in-linux-c

And is also documented at http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, this would actually help even though you can't access `/proc/*` OSX. I don't mind. Do you know of a similar solution for disk I/O ?